# Generating ANT result report from Selenium + JUnit using intellij IDEA

Tags: java, selenium, ant, junit, intellij-idea

I am not verse in ANT and also very new to development work, and i need to generate a result report(pass/fail) of some kind for my test project. I use intellij, selenium web-driver and junit.

I research on this topic and most point to using ANT to generate the report.
however, most example is to much for me to understand. I hope some one could point me in the right direction,  I am not even sure on how to setup ANT for intellij for my test-cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use ANT to run my test with out IDE (intellij), you can run your test through ant and generate xml/html reports:

```
 <target name="tests" depends="build">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr" showoutput="true" outputtoformatters="true" haltonfailure="no"
               failureproperty="test.failed">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="com.tests.ExampleTests" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="seleniumproject.classpath"/>
        </junit>
        <fail message="Test failure detected, check test results." if="test.failed"/>
 </target>

 <target name="junitreport">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    </junitreport>
 </target>
```

I run it through Continues Integration or some .bat file
My Project dir

```
-- Ant
-- MyProject
    -- test
    -- build.xml
    -- run-test.bat
    -- run-tests-unx.sh
```

Script from .bat file:

```
@echo OFF
color 0a
echo:
echo Test is Running...
echo:
echo Run all selenium tests
echo Working directory: %~dp0
echo:
echo:
set LOG=Rebuild.log
%~dp0..\ant\bin\ant.bat tests -buildfile %~dp0build.xml -logfile %LOG%
```

Script for unix .sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Test is Running...";
dir=$(pwd);
echo $dir;
cd ..
echo ${PWD}
dir2=$(pwd);
cd $dir;
$dir2/ant/bin/ant tests -buildfile $dir/build.xml -logfile $dir/Rebuild.log
```

You can run through cmd:

```
/ant/bin/ant.bat [your target name] -buildfile [your build.xml]
```

Ant will generate something like this (junit-reports): 
[image: junit reports]

You will open index.html to see results:

[image: junit resutls]

Comment: Thank you Andrian!
For any intellij user that need to build a ANT xml,
Go build > Generate ANT build (choose name and general configuration)
Now you can add junit report code into the xml